# How to access File from local network which I shared through "Media Sharing feature" in setting option

Tags: networking, permissions, file-sharing, rygel

I am trying to access ubuntu folder from my android phone. I know there may some other option available. but I saw there is a option available in setting which is `sharing > media sharing`. after I turn on I saw my ubuntu pc is visible on network. but problem is I don't find any folder.

**from mobile side:** I am using a file manager which has a feature to access files from local network. I found my PC is visible on local network. so I tried to connect. since there is no option for password and user in media sharing  setting, so I thought i can connect without auth. but problem is I can connect anonymously but it don't show me any folder.

I think I am missing anything. could anyone help  how to connect from another device with this feature **media sharing feature**. May be its running with `rygel`.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1480055/edit) and add this information.

Comment: You need to use a UPNP/DLNA player app like VLC for Android in your Android phone to play the shared multimedia. I think you also have to be logged in to your Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @user68186 I am using ubuntu version 22.04.2

Comment: @user68186 and yes I was logged in my ubuntu. and I also tried from my android phone.  what kind of protocol it is using under the hood ? like if I share any folder to network is use Samba smd protocol. so what kind of protocol  this `media sharing` feature use ?

Comment: It uses UPNP/DLNA protocol. You need to use a media player that supports this protocol, such as VLC for Android.